# DocuSign SharePoint Online app

Tags: docusignapi

Wonder if anyone has used the app to sign documents inside of a document set?

It seems like there is an issue with URLs being passed while doing so.

Looking at the communication, initial request is fine: https://partner.docusign.net/Partners/MSSharePoint/SignSend?...
SourceUrl= ....  contains all parameters including &FolderID

but last request and return to referrer: 
https://partner.docusign.net/partners/mssharepoint/EscapeIFrame?SourceUrl= .... trims of any additional parameters (e.g. &FolderID)

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently we **don't support document sets**, only single documents.

We can add a feature request to our backlog for future consideration.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. 
I was actually aiming to sign a single document residing into a Document Set. Is that supported?